# Displaying the list of pictures from downloaded url

Tags: react-native

How I can display a list of pictures? I get the list URL ( local address)  from DB.

```json
[
  {"employeId": 1, "name": "Mariusz", "url": "../assets/servicesIcons/baleyage.png"}, 
  {"employeId": 2, "name": "Mariola", "url": "../assets/servicesIcons/baleyage.png"}, 
  {"employeId": 3, "name": "Rafal", "url": "../assets/servicesIcons/baleyage.png"}
]
```

```
const HoursComponent = ({id, time}) => {
    const TimewithoutLast3 = time.slice(0, -3);
    return (
        <View style={{...styles.rootContainer, backgroundColor: bgColor}}>
            <TouchableOpacity >
                <Text style={styles.buttonText} onPress={onPress}>{TimewithoutLast3}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
}




 <FlatList
              numColumns={3}
              data={employee}
              keyExtractor={item => item.id}
              renderItem={({ item }) => (<EmployeeComponet {...item} />)}></FlatList>
```

I try using require but it doesn't work

Comment: Can you look at this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74172026/react-native-dynamically-load-tons-of-small-images/74175309#74175309

Comment: What doesn't work exactly? Do you get an error that the file is missing? Do you get an empty screen? Could you please show us the section where the actual image is added in your code? I don't think, that anybody is able to help you without providing the code that causes you the problem in first place.

Answer (score 0):

I try add somthing like this but is not working
example url value '../../assets/servicesIcons/test.png'

```
<Image  source={{require:("\'" + url  +  "\'")}} />
```

but when I added static value then is ok.

```
const value = require('../../assets/servicesIcons/test.png');
...
<Image  source={value} />
```

Answer (score -1):

Import Image from react native and use Image tag like

```
const HoursComponent = ({employeId, name, url}) => {
    const TimewithoutLast3 = time.slice(0, -3);
    return (
        <View style={{...styles.rootContainer, backgroundColor: bgColor}}>
            <TouchableOpacity >
                <Text style={styles.buttonText} onPress={onPress}>{name}</Text>
<Image source={{uri :url}}  /> 
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
}

 <FlatList
              numColumns={3}
              data={employee}
              keyExtractor={item => item.employeId}
              renderItem={({ item }) => (<EmployeeComponet {...item} />)}></FlatList>
```

Comment: using `source={{uri: url}}`will not help him on local uri's. He needs to use `source={require(url)}`. Please look at his data, these are local uri's and not web links.